# Show dropdown Filter with single value in the datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using data table, And the column values are (tag1, tag2, tag3) Comma separated
I have created a dropdown filter for that column

and the values of that dropdown are like the column values (tag1, tag2, tag3) Comma separated

But I need a single value for each option in the drop-down

tag1

tag2

tag3

and so on

Here is the code

```
initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns([1]).every(function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = jQuery('<select id="test-haris"><option value=""></option> 
            < /select>')
                .appendTo(jQuery(column.header()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = jQuery.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        jQuery(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This question looks very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087389/split-the-comma-separated-values-of-a-column-1-tags-and-make-a-dropdown-filter) you asked a few hours ago.

Comment: And I see you have also asked the same question on the [DataTables site forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/176066). I think we are all struggling to understand the question. Can you provide a sample of your JSON data - and, based on that, describe what you want to see in each drop-down? Maybe that will help to clarify the problem.

Comment: @andrewjames please see this image https://ibb.co/kDPpSYk                                              Maybe it will help to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach builds a select list (a drop-down) from the contents of the first column.

For each cell in that column, it splits the comma-separated items into separate pieces of text, and then creates a sorted, unique list for the drop-down.

When you search by selecting an item from the drop-down, it checks if the selected item is contained anywhere in the text of each cell in that column. It uses a custom DataTables filter for this.

In my case, I placed the drop-down in the footer of the table - you can change that.

The table looks like this:

[image]

And here is the drop-down:

[image]

When an item is selected from the drop-down, you can see the filtering in effect:

[image]

The code for this solution is as follows - I have split it up into separate sections/functions to try to make the structure and approach clearer:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger , John, Nixon , </td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John, Garrett , Winters , </td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton, Winters , Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric , Kelly , Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // the DataTable object:  
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    select: false // or, whatever you need in here.
  } );

  // Setup - add a select list to first footer cell:
  $('#example tfoot th').slice(0, 1).each( function () {
    var dropdown = buildDropdown();
    $(this).html( dropdown );
  } );


  // add a change event to the select list:
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {
    table.draw();
  });


  // create a custom search function for the select list,
  // which finds if the selected item is contained in the cell:
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
      var selectedValue = $('#mySelect').val();
      console.log(selectedValue);
      if (data[0].includes(selectedValue)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  );


  function buildDropdown() {
    var selectHtml;
    // this will hold array of distinct values:
    var items = [];
    table.columns([0]).data().each(function (data, index) {
      data.forEach(function (newItems, index) {
        newItems.split(',').forEach(function (newItem, index) {
          if ( newItem.trim() !== '' && items.indexOf(newItem) === -1) {
            items.push(newItem.trim());
          }
        });
      });
    });
    // sort and remove duplicates:
    var uniqueSortedItems = [...new Set(items)].sort();

    selectHtml = '<select id="mySelect"><option value=""></option>';
    uniqueSortedItems.forEach(function(item) { 
      selectHtml = selectHtml + '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
    });
    selectHtml = selectHtml + '</select>';

    return selectHtml;
  }


} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you are trying to achieve - but you will need to integrate this into your specific solution, of course.

You will also need to decide what you want to do about **the global search function** (if you are using it), because it may interfere with the custom search used for the first column.

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I want to achieve Let me modify it accordingly Thanks :)